# Vectorwise to Hive using Sqoop

Tags: hive, sqoop

I've been trying to import a table from Vectorwise to Hive using Sqoop. I downloaded the Vectorwise JDBC driver and all. It just ain't working.

This is the command I'm using:
sudo -u hdfs sqoop import --driver com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver --connect jdbc:ingres://172.16.63.157:VW7/amit --username ingres -password ingres --table vector_table --hive-table=vector_table --hive-import --create-hive-table -m 1

And I'm getting the error:
12/06/07 22:08:27 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:635)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:53)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:524)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:547)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:191)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:175)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:263)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1226)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1051)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:84)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:370)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:456)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:182)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:221)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:230)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:239)

I'd really appreciate it if someone can help me out here.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it working. It was a simple permission issue. I changed the owner of iijdbc.jar to hdfs.

sudo chown hdfs /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/iijdbc.jar

Now it's working! :)

I can now import my Vectorwise tables to Hive using Sqoop. Great!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so as an answer:

This is a quote from the [documentation](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_connecting_to_a_database_server):

> You can use Sqoop with any other JDBC-compliant database. First,
>   download the appropriate JDBC driver for the type of database you want
>   to import, and install the .jar file in the $SQOOP_HOME/lib directory
>   on your client machine. (This will be /usr/lib/sqoop/lib if you
>   installed from an RPM or Debian package.) Each driver .jar file also
>   has a specific driver class which defines the entry-point to the
>   driver. For example, MySQL’s Connector/J library has a driver class of
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. Refer to your database vendor-specific
>   documentation to determine the main driver class. This class must be
>   provided as an argument to Sqoop with --driver.

Do you have the proper jar file in a directory that's accessible by Sqoop?

For the future it is also always useful if you give a bit more information about your environment like which version of Sqoop you are using etc.

Comment: Yeah, I have the iijdbc.jar file (from the JDBC download in vectorwise's site) in the /usr/lib/sqoop/lib folder. I'm using sqoop v1.3.0-cdh3u4